# How to read windows desktop date format from VBA (suitable to pass to Format() function)

Tags: vba, excel

I am calling the Excel Range.Find method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.15%29.aspx

And apparently it requires that if searching a DATE, that the date value must be passed in a format consistent with the running Windows Desktop date format.

So what I need to do at runtime is detect the Date format of Windows (dd/mm/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy, etc) so I can use that to format my Date variable when calling the Range.Find function.

**From VBA, how can one read the Windows Date Format for the current user?**

Answer (score 1):

This function works for all the testing I've done running Range.Find() with various date configurations.  I can't help feeling there's got to be a better way to do this as this is simply not a reasonable solution for a VBA developer to come up with on their own.....yet this is Microsoft, and VBA.

```
Public Function WindowsShortFormattedDate(dt As Date) As String
    Dim sDay As String, sMonth As String, sYear As String, seperator As String
    seperator = Application.International(xlDateSeparator)
    sDay = IIf(Application.International(xlDayLeadingZero), Format(day(dt), "00"), Format(day(dt), "0"))
    sMonth = IIf(Application.International(xlMonthLeadingZero), Format(month(dt), "00"), Format(month(dt), "0"))    'it "seems" Excel never shows MMM even if thats what you've chosen under windows settings
    sYear = IIf(Application.International(xl4DigitYears), Format(year(dt), "0000"), Format(year(dt), "00"))
    Select Case Application.International(xlDateOrder)
        Case 0 'month-day-year
            WindowsShortFormattedDate = sMonth & seperator & sDay & seperator & sYear
        Case 1 'day - month - year
            WindowsShortFormattedDate = sDay & seperator & sMonth & seperator & sYear
        Case 2 'year - month - day
            WindowsShortFormattedDate = sYear & seperator & sMonth & seperator & sDay
        Case Else
            err.Raise -999, "WindowsShortFormattedDate", "Unanticipated xlDateOrder"
    End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If:

```
Sub DateFormatTest()
    MsgBox Left(DateSerial(2000, 12, 25), 2)
End Sub
```

displays **12** then the format is mm/dd/yyyy
displays **25** then the format is dd/mm/yyyy

The alternative is to plod thru **Application.International** which, on a good day, is painful.

Comment: I came across this approach, have you investigated this fairly deeply so you can say this is the ONLY way?  Because there are MANY other possible permutations.  Microsoft drives me insane sometimes.

Comment: We are only looking at the first two characters....we might get a better handle by looking at more.